# Does Wakanda follow the Sokovia Accords?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018, black-panther

When several Wakandan ambassadors are accidentally killed in the events of *Captain America: Civil War*, the Sokovia Accords are created to regulate the actions of powered/enhanced people. Because of the death of their ambassadors, Wakanda leads the effort to enact the Accords.

However, Wakanda has its own hero that it hides from the world in the form of Black Panther. He's not the only one, though. People like Nakia, Okoye, and Shuri are all performing hero operations without UN oversight.

After the events of *Black Panther*, in which Wakanda opens itself up to the world, do the enhanced individuals of Wakanda have to follow the Sokovia Accords (or have they been)?

Comment: Nakia, Okoye, and Shuri aren't enhanced (yet...) , as I understand it. I don't think the accords apply to geniuses or good fighters, or any unenhanced individual, except those in the Avengers. Of course, they're still conducting covert operations in another nation, but that's pretty common (think the death of Osama bin Laden). Illegal, but mainly only if you're caught.

Comment: @Adamant I thought that technology qualified you for enhancement. For example, Shuri's vibranium gauntlets and Nakia's ring blades aren't generally used by other people throughout the world (I assume). And I don't understand why the Accords wouldn't apply to those individuals, especially considering the fact that some of their heroic efforts have left casualties (physically or mentally).

Comment: I don't think they go into detail, but I don't think technology counts unless it's pretty much part of you.

Comment: Considering how the Sokovia Accords played out in practice, and the people Wakanda are sheltering because of the Accords, I think it's pretty doubtful they'd stick by the letter of the law in the end.

Comment: to just add on to what @Adamant said, despite Tony using an enhanced suit in *Iron Man 2*, to prevent himself having to hand over the Iron Man Suit Tony claimed that he and the suit are one so to deliver the suit would be to deliver himself which he compares to slavery

Comment: I don't think we know all that much about the exact terms of the accords.  The description on the Wiki suggests that it only covers enhanced individuals working for government agencies and/or private organizations.  Black Panther is a head of state, which might not qualify.

Comment: I also want to point out that in Ant-Man and the Wasp, Jimmy Woo, an FBI agent, points out that giving tech in order to enhance an individual illegally also violates the Accords, so Shuri would be in violation of the Accords as well if her activity wasn't sanctioned.

Comment: In Civil War, almost immediately after Wakanda signs the accords, T'Chala gets arrested trying to kill Bucky Barnes. I don't think he follows the Accords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont see why not, as the sovereign on Wakanda, the Black panther basically Monitors himself thus keeping to the accord

> Any enhanced individuals who sign are prohibited from taking action in any country other than their own, unless they are first given clearance by either that country's government or by a United Nations subcommittee.

so in this sense the Black Panther can do what he wants as he is the head of his government and as a member of the UN he has already followed the following regulations

> Any enhanced individuals who agree to sign must register with the United Nations and provide biometric data such as fingerprints and DNA samples.
>
> Those with secret identities must reveal their legal names and true identities to the United Nations.
> Those with innate powers must submit to a power analysis, which will categorize their threat level and determine potential health risks.

and in the Black panther Movie the necklace has a tracking device in thus fulfilling the last requirements:

> Those with innate powers must also wear tracking bracelets at all times.

Comment: The trick is that he's operating in other countries, though.

Comment: Maybe? The wording says "countries other than their own."